# How to Unit Test a Method in a Vue.js Component using jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to unit test a component method. The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520835/vue-and-jest-unit-testing-components) does not lay out how to access the component method from a unit test.

Specifically, given my Vue component below, how do I access `doSomeWork()` from my unit test?

*Vue component:*

```html
<template>
    <div id="ThisStuff">
        <span>
            Some other stuff is going on here
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import foo from 'bar'

    export default {
        props: {
            ObjectWithStuffInIt: [
                {
                    id: 1
                    bar: false
                },
                {
                    id: 2
                    bar: false
                },
            ]
        },
        data: {
            foo: "foo"
        },
        methods: {
            doSomeWork: function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < ObjectWithStuffInIt.length; i++) { 
                    if (foo === "diddly") {
                        ObjectWithStuffInIt[i].bar = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

*My test code:*

```js
import {createLocalVue, shallow} from 'vue-test-utils'
import ThisVueFile.test.js from '../../thisPlace/ThatPlace/ThisVueFile.vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex);

describe('ThisVueFile.test.js', () => {
    let user;
    let store;

    beforeEach(() => {
        let getters = {
            user: () => user
        }

        store = new Vuex.Store({ getters })
    })

    // I need to fill propsData: with some local data here 
    //     because it is server data
    // I need to have access to the method
    // I need to use local data for `foo` in the test. 

    it(' When foo is set to -diddly- then set bar to true ', () => {
        foo = "diddly";
        // run the method in the component here 
        doSomeWork();

        expect(OjbectWithStuffInIt[0].bar.equals(true));
    })
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue and Jest unit testing components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520835/vue-and-jest-unit-testing-components)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

#### Calling component method

The wrapper provides access to the component instance via its [`vm`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#vm) property, so you could call the method directly with:

```js
wrapper.vm.doSomeWork()
```

#### Setting `props`

- The mounting options (passed to [`shallowMount()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/shallowMount.html) or [`mount()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/mount.html)) include the [`propsData`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#propsdata) property that could be used to initialize the component's `props` before mounting.
- You could also use the wrapper's [`setProps()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setprops) after the component has already been mounted.

*Example:*

```js
it('...', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    propsData: {
      myItems: [
        { id: 200, bar: false },
        { id: 300, bar: false }
      ]
    }
  });

  // OR
  wrapper.setProps({
    myItems: [
      { id: 400: bar: true }
    ]
  })
})
```

#### Modifying component data property

- The mounting options includes the [`data`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#data) property that could be used to initialize the component's data before mounting.
- You could also use the wrapper's [`setData()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setdata) after the component has already mounted.
- You could access the component's data property directly through the wrapper's `vm` property.

*Example:*

```js
it('...', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    data() {
      return {
        foo: 1
      }
    }
  });

  // OR
  wrapper.setData({ foo: 2 })

  // OR
  wrapper.vm.foo = 3
})
```

#### Full example

Altogether, your test might look similar to this:

```js
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('When foo is set to -something-, set bar to true', () => {
    const myItems = [
      { id: 200, bar: false },
      { id: 300, bar: false }
    ]
    const localVue = createLocalVue()
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        myItems
      }
    })

    wrapper.vm.foo = 'something'
    wrapper.vm.doSomeWork()

    expect(myItems[0].bar).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wq71jpm1l7?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.spec.js&previewwindow=tests)